# How do I defeat Beamos?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm wandering around, lost, in Lanayru Mining Facility.  As I was blundering about, I took a (horizontal) swipe at a Beamos and surprisingly, did some damage.  I've also noticed that a targeting arrow appears when I get close.  **Can I kill these guys?**  If so, how?

[image: Beamos, from The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword]

Comment: Why would you ever want to kill [BMO](http://28.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpy6tfhL8L1r0wh1oo1_400.gif)!?

Comment: That thing has a name??

Comment: @Joe A I like to think it should be capitalized: BeamOS.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The **video game rule of vulnerability** comes into play here: **Hit 'em in the glowy bits**. You can never go wrong hitting anything that glows. In this case that means slashing horizontally to cut the blue lines between the "blocks" that make up the body then stabbing the glowing eye. Or just arrow the eye if you have the bow.

The same rule of thumb applies to Armos and Bombos as well.

Comment: That's a rule every gamer _must_ know.

Comment: I also discovered that after you hack them down to size, you can use the Gust Bellows to disorient them, which gives you a chance to stab them before they zap you again and again and again and again...

Comment: I never tried that, I just go slashy-stabby on them immediately. ;)

Answer (score 8):

If you can break enough of its segments to bring it down to ground level, you can kill it by stabbing it in the eye.  (ow!)  Otherwise, you can put an arrow in its eye (Oblig. "I used to be a Beamos, until I took an arrow to my eye" joke) if you've already found the Bow.

From [IGN's Wiki guide](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/Beamos):

> Slicing the Beamos's different sections vertically (separated by the blue running line across) will bring its head to the ground. A thrust into the eye will finish it off. You can also keep out of its reach and then shoot it in the "eye" with an arrow once the Bow is obtained.

Comment: Is it me, or is `vertically` the opposite of what you want to be doing?

Comment: @Rawling I see what they're trying to say, but the meaning isn't clear. Perhaps it was written by a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 3):

You can also dizzy them first by blowing on their head with your blow gun

Answer (score 1):

I always took them out with horizontal slashes, or spins.
2x, then stab the eye.

If he's on you, run a fair distance away then try again.

Strangely enough, you can stun them with a perfect shield bash if you have a wooden shield or sacred shield.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have [the bow](http://www.zeldawiki.org/Bow), you can kill them from a distance with a single shot to the "eye".  This is especially helpful on the Sandship when trying to defeat [the two Beamos in the big key room](http://www.zeldadungeon.net/Zelda14-skyward-sword-walkthrough-12.php#C12_3).

Answer (score -1):

As previous answers suggest, hit them in the glowy bits. For Beamos, use horizontal slashes to cut him down to size, then poke him in the eye (with a thrust).

Comment: -1 This seems more like a rant than an answer.

Comment: FYI, shield bash works well for Technoblins.